# Vertical Sliding of xib while we drag using finger using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, slide

I have a Main view(currently displayed view).

AnotherView is added as a subview to a scrollview.The initial position of this AnotherView has to be in such a way that the bottom of this another view appears on the top most portion of the MainView.

Now,when I drag the AnotherView's bottom portion downwards,AnotherView should get displayed as SLIDING from top to bottom with the speed I drag it.

When I stop dragging,the sliding also should halt.

If I release the dragging after half of the screen,the sliding should continue to bottom of the screen.

How could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use UIPanGestureRecognizer. 
AnotherView should be in front of main or put it to front in Pan recogniser's function on UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.
If UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged change anotherView frame accordingly to this movement. You can get movement by [panRecognizer translationInView:self.view] which returns CGPoint. And check if Another view is already after half of the screen. If you pass half of the screen, just use animateWithDuration to finish movement on UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded.
So another view doesn't need to be inside scrollview.

As far as I understood, you want to make something similar to sliding out menu. http://www.raywenderlich.com/32054/how-to-create-a-slide-out-navigation-like-facebook-and-path 
There you can find example how to use pan recognizer to slide view by dragging.